# How to upload file to a server with php - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I have problem with upload file to a server with php.

This is my code testForm.php

```
    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $sta["status"] = "Success";
        echo stripslashes(json_encode($sta)); 
    }
```

And in livecode

```
 put the text of field "pF" into pathFile
 put urlEncode("file:"& pathFile) into tFile
 put libUrlFormData("userfile",tFile) into tArgList
 post tArgList to URL "http://localhost:9999/livecodeTestJson/testForm.php"
```

It's not working.

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't tell me where to look for the problem. Why isn't it working? Does the wrong file get uploaded? Does the file get uploaded and stored in the wrong place? Do you get any error messages in LiveCode or in PHP? What value is in "the result" after issuing the post command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know, if your php code is correct, but your livecode part isn´t.

To post files to a webserver you need the libUrlMultipartFormData function.

Below you find a sample from the libURL documentatin. I adjusted it a little bit using your values

```
 put empty into tFormData
    put "http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/form.cgi" into tUrl
    put the text of field "pF" into pathFile
    put "<file>" & pathfile into tFile
    if libUrlMultipartFormData(tFormData, "userfile", tFile) is not empty then
      answer it ##error
    else
      set the httpHeaders to line 1 of tFormData
      post line 2 to -1 of tFormData to url tUrl 
      ## check the result, etc., here
      set the httpHeaders to empty
    end if
```

If you also want post form data then you have to include that data in the call of the libURLMultiPartFormData.

Let´s say you have the form fields "name", "email" and "message" and the variables tName, tEmail and tMessage contain the data then you would replace line 5 of the sample script with the following line

```
 if libUrlMultipartFormData(tFormData, "name", tName, "email", tEmail, "message", tMessage, "userfile", tFile) is not empty
```

Comment: If I want to upload file and submit data from form.How do I do ?

Comment: I extended my answer to answer your new question.